# Is there way to redirect all blog post pages to Home page?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am creating a social bookmarking site using WordPress.

I am using a custom field to store the web URL. Then when a user clicks the Title, it redirects to the original blog post page.

Please check this one: http://popurls.com/ (I am creating a site like this one).

I don't need blog posts because I want to save the Title, one Custom Field to save the URL, Category and Tag only. But in WordPress, there is a blank page created automatically, and even blog description is null.

So when a user submits a URL, one page is automatically created.

Is there way to redirect all blog post pages to Home page (only blog POST pages, not normal pages)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code. Have your tried this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: Do you need the page URLs? Are you dispal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myself found the answer.

I added `<?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.mydomainname.com', 301 ); exit; ?>` in single.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Doable, I think, if you're ready to custom code a loop which will modify the post titles' link urls.

With a custom field called `title_link`, your code could end up looking something like this:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <!-- post -->
        <?php $titleLink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title_link', true); ?>
        <h1><a href="<?php echo $titleLink; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div> <!-- /post -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Credit to this guy [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-link-on-post-titles?replies=6).

Answer (score -1):

You want to redirect all those pages which have a post type "post", to redirect all those pages we will write this in the first line before even html tag:

```
if((get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'post' ) && !is_home() ) 
{
  header("Location: " . home_url());
}
```

Explanation: `get_post_type( get_the_ID() )`checks whether the current page being displayed is post, we also need to check whether the page is home page or not through `is_home()` otherwise we will get a redirect loop error.

Comment: Add that in header.php

Comment: Add that to your answer (not as a comment). Also explain _why_ this should help solving the problem presented in the question.

Comment: Answer modified with the better explanation and even the code has been tried myself too :) Thanks for the guidance!!!